# name is not defined in Python for loop

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame 'total_data' which I want to filter and divide into several subsets, using .query() method and 'for' loop. I have conditions written as strings for each subset.
Here's my code:

```
subsets = ['subset1', 'subset2']
subset1_query = 'Column1 in @list1, Column2 in @list2'
subset2_query = 'Column3 in @list3, Column4 in @list4'

for subset in subsets:
    query_sub = subset+'_query'
    total_data.query(query_sub).to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name = subset)
```

But I get an error: **name 'subset1_query' is not defined.**
While when I use total_data.query(subset1_query) out of the loop I get a correct dataframe.
Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do is this here:

```
subsets = ['subset1', 'subset2']
subset1_query = 'Column1 in @list1, Column2 in @list2'
subset2_query = 'Column3 in @list3, Column4 in @list4'

for subset in subsets:
    query_sub = subset+'_query'
    total_data.query(**eval**(query_sub)).to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name = subset)
```

But the question for me is, why don't you put the two subset_1|2_query Objects in the list, i.e.

```
subsets = [('subset1', 'Column1 in @list1, Column2 in @list2'), ('subset2', 'Column3 in @list3, Column4 in @list4')]
for subset_name, query_sub in subsets:
        total_data.query(query_sub).to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name = subset_name)
```

Wouldn't that be a bit more straightforward?

Edit: I fixed something in the second example to more fit your question. I overlooked something at first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It actually made me realise that I can do this using dictionary with name of subset and query conditions and then just loop through dict.items()